# Docker & OpenEdge 11.7.2

Tags: windows, docker, containers, openedge, progress-db

I have successfully managed to install Progress OpenEdge 11.6 32bit, 11.7 32bit and 11.7.1 32bit inside a Docker container, using the response.ini file.

However, I cannot find a way to make 11.7.2 32bit working, and it's getting quite frustrating. When using **proadsv -query** or **proadsv -start** or **proadsv -stop** inside the container, I receive the standard 'OpenEdge Release + [time stamp here]' message yet nothing more.

I believe the issue may have something to do with Java paths, but I'm not sure.

**NOTE**: I have a host machine with Windows and the container in which I'm trying to install OpenEdge 11.7.2 has Windows Core in it as well.

I have had a look over the dockerfile and response.ini that Mr. Bronco has in his github page here https://github.com/bfv/docker4oe but he has done some stuff for Suse Linux, and I am exclusively interested in Windows.

Is there any solution for this?

Upon installing, I am looking int he installation log and every single component appears to install successfully though.

Answer (score 4):

Well, since I'm the one you mentioned, Windows Core is not a supported platform (see: https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000041790) platform. For that reason I never tested it myself. This lack of support may well be the root cause for what you're experiencing. Since Docker is normally used as a "one process per container" using the AdminServer is not really standard practice. If it's about database, you may as well start them with proserve (providing that works at all).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I would like to emphasize once more that I did manage to successfully install in a container with Windows Core OpenEdge 11.7 and 11.7.1 and they work just fine. It's just 11.7.2 that is giving me trouble.

Comment: Assuming you pay maintenance you can always call TechSupport. Most of the time they're quite helpful, even with non-supported setups.

Comment: @SimpleFuzz Can I ask what you want to do with the OpenEdge Docker Container? We've also tried setting it up without a lot of success. I actually would like to have OE Docker Containers to compile ABL Source code into r-code.